# django get to know what submodel is associated to the main model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model called `Animal` and there are multiple models that have `Animal` as `OneToOneField`

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField()

class Cat(models.Model):
    animal = models.OneToOneField(Animal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Dog(models.Model):
    animal = models.OneToOneField(Animal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Lion(models.Model):
    animal = models.OneToOneField(Animal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

(nb . there are 50 submodels)
Only When an ad is created , so it will associated to only one of 50 submodel car,boat or truck 
so after that i am creating a view to display the name of the Animal but how can i know what is the sub model associated to the ad to get the data from it to.

```
def get_ad_details(request, id):
    animal = Animal.objects.get(id=id)

    #need to call a method to get a boat or car or truck or .... that is associated to the ad so how?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way would be to use model inheritance and then [use `InheritanceManager` from `django-model-utils` package](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager).

If you do not want to do that you can take a look at its code for inspiration. Essentially you'd need to cycle throw every possible related field to see which one is set, so in your example it would be something like:

```py
def get_ad_details(request, id):
    possible_related_models = ['car', 'boat', 'truck']
    ad = Ad.objects.get(id=id).select_related(possible_related_models)  # select_related prevents one query for each model afterwards

    #need to call a method to get a boat or car or truck or .... that is associated to the ad so how?
    relboject = None
    for relmodel in possible_related_models:
        relobject = getattr(ad, relmodel, None)
        if relobject:
            break
```

Comment: Thank you ivissani, please can you tell me in the second case how can i get all the possible_related_models without the need to type them all because i have around 50 sub models

Comment: Only easy way I can think of is iterating over every attribute of `ad` and of those who are models see which ones have a FK to AD. Cannot extend me on this now, will try to explain more tonight. In the meantime you can take a look at how [its done here](https://jeffelmore.org/2010/11/11/automatic-downcasting-of-inherited-models-in-django/) although it's not the exact same case

Comment: how can i cast the relobject to the given model , so if relobject is a Car so Car c = relobject then , or if Animal so Animal a = relobject so i can access attributes of them

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, since you have `OneToOne` relations by doing `getattr(ad, 'car')` it is the same as doing `ad.car` which returns a proper `Car`

Comment: Besides Python is dynamically typed meaning that at runtime you can access the attributes if they exist, you don't need to cast anything..

Comment: What i have is an update form so when i click on a product it should open a page display the inputs of the Product and the fields of the model having a onetoone relationship belonging to it so that is my problem i want to call the form of the model having onetoone relation to the parent model

Comment: When you say "open" you mean redirect?

Comment: i have an edit form so when i want to edit an item i want to display its main fields and get the fields of the onetoone model associated to the main model